# What's wrong in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, client-side

I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
var CarObj = function(passengers, maxLoad, wheels, doors, maxSpeed) {
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.maxLoad = maxLoad;
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.doors = doors;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
};
var ferrari = new CarObj(4, "700kg", 4, 2, "360km/h");
var output = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < ferrari.length; i++) {
    for (var a in ferrari) {
        output[i] = a;
    }
}
document.getElementById('ELEMENTHERE').innerHTML = (output.join(" "));
```

Comment: What it supposed to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: It's supposed to to output the things (what are they called again? Specifications?) in the ferrari carobject, but it ends up not doing anything.

Comment: You could have tried `alert(ferrari.length)` and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < ferrari.length; i++) {
```

`ferrari` is not an Array, but you are trying to access it like it is. Remove this and its corresponding end brace.

You also should change `output[i] = ...;` to `output.push(...);` or `output[output.length] = ...;`, which would eliminate the need to increment `i` manually.

Comment: Then how am I going to get the counter I need?

Comment: @DarkLightA: Added that to the answer above

Answer (score 1):

From what i'm seeing, your `for...in` is looping over the same object that the outer `for` is.  This will set every item of `output` to the last key of `ferrari`, if `ferrari` has a length -- or give you errors about undefined properties if it doesn't.

What you probably wanted to do instead:

```
for (var a in ferrari) {
    output[output.length] = a; // or ferrari[a] if you wanted values, not keys
}
```

and get rid of the outer `for` loop entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i in ferrari) output.push(ferrari[i]);
```

It'd be a little more robust to do:

```
for (var i in ferrari)
  if (ferrari.hasOwnProperty(i))
    output.push(ferrari[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
i = 0;
for (var a in ferrari) {
    output[i++] = a;
}
```

?
ferrari does not have length property.

Comment: The counter isn't necessary.  Arrays expand automagically (and the length updates appropriately), so `output.length` can be used as the index of the item to append.

Answer (score 0):

ferrai is an Object and it doesn't have a property by name length (an array does).
Change your code to as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var CarObj = function(passengers, maxLoad, wheels, doors, maxSpeed) {     
            this.passengers = passengers;     
            this.maxLoad = maxLoad;     
            this.wheels = wheels;     
            this.doors = doors;     
            this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed; 
        }; 
        var ferrari = new CarObj(4, "700kg", 4, 2, "360km/h"); 
        var output = new Array(); 
        var i=0;
            for (var a in ferrari) 
            {
                output[i] = a;     
                i++;
            } 
        document.getElementById('ELEMENTHERE').innerHTML = (output.join(" "));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just override the toString() for the object?

```
var CarObj = function(passengers, maxLoad, wheels, doors, maxSpeed) {
  this.passengers = passengers;
  this.maxLoad = maxLoad;
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.doors = doors;
  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  this.toString = function() {
    return this.passengers + " " + this.maxLoad + " " + this.wheels + " " + this.doors + " " + this.maxSpeed;
  };
};
```